# How to install more than one OS on a pendrive?

Tags: linux, system-installation, dual-boot, usb-drive, bootable

I have a Windows 10 laptop. While I want to use Linux based OS I don't want to partition my HD or remove Windows OS. So I thought of installing Ubuntu on a 64gb pendrive and running the OS from it. But is it possible to install 2 OS on same pendrive like Ubuntu + mint and have a choice everytime I boot? Also if I am running OS from a USB drive will I get full access? And where do I install all the softwares for Linux? Is it possible to do that on the pendrive itself? So that the pendrive can become my own personal little Hard drive which can turn any PC/laptop into my own with all my softwares, data and settings? Kind of like my whole c drive is on the pendrive and I can access other drives(data like videos, music,etc) from the computer's hard drive. And if I connect the pendrive to some other computer my c drive stays with me so all the work I do or data I save still stays with me when I go back to my PC. Plus OS is locked and always with me in my pocket so even if someone tries to use my laptop my data is safe with me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You can use too a Cloud Storage, Like Dropbox ou Google Drive to help.

You can use the [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create the multi boot device. But you will not have persistent storage with it.

So you can use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a single OS boot but with persistent storage. Then you will be able to install e configure your OS as you wish.

Using windows 10 you won't be able to access the C drive. You will need to disable Windows Quick Boot. I am not able to show you the link, but you will have to search for it.

Comment: So I either two OS or one OS with persistent storage? You can't ever get everything you want in this world, can you?

Comment: Maybe there is a way. This is what I know. Maybe you can search for another solution.

Comment: Maybe a full install in the USB Drive can help  you, Did you tried?

Comment: Here are some tips for you https://www.maketecheasier.com/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-install-usb/

Comment: I could install both OS on the same USB drive but then don't you think extracted files would clash? Or if I make 2 different folder like partitioning a hard drive I wonder if they would autorun on booting the PC and ask me which one to run.. Still I'll surely try that.